# Synch between Git and Overleaf

Tags: git, github, overleaf

I work on two repositories at Git - one created by someone else (Dan) and one created by me. The one created by me synchs perfectly with Overleaf. When I choose "Import from GitHub" from I can only see my one, but not the other one. Any help? I'm new to Git (experienced at Overleaf) so I don't know how to push from Git to Overleaf?

Comment: I don't have exp with Overleaf, but this is most likley because Overleaf is only listing your repo. Dan's repo is not in your list of repos and so you can't see it. You can try forking Dan's repo into your Github and then try again (see if you can see it now)

Comment: P.S. This is not a git question. Instead a Overleaf UI/UX question